# C# auto-Suggestion Box Error

Tags: c#, database

I am using a textbox, and in this textbox whenever i enter a text it gives me suggestions from my database column.It 60% works fine and it successfully gives me the suggestion from the database but sometimes the program crashes when i write on a textbox.Here's below my code:

private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
     try
        {
            textBox5.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            textBox5.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            AutoCompleteStringCollection col = new 
             AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            con.Open();
            string sql = ("select * from Table1 union all select * from table2 union all select * from table3 union all select * from table4 union all select * from table5");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            SqlDataReader sdr = null;
            sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                col.Add(sdr["Player1"].ToString());
                col.Add(sdr["Player2"].ToString());
            }
            sdr.Close();

            textBox5.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col;
            con.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Here player1 and player2 are my fields in table1,table2,table3,table4,table5.It crashes when i wrote on textbox5 (which is my suggestion textbox).I have selected NONE in both autocomplete and autosuggest properties of textbox5.

Will be very Thankful for your help.

Comment: Maybe you should be handling the KeyUp event instead of TextChanged?

Comment: We can't help you without the exception details (message, type, stack-trace). Also, use `using()` instead of manually closing your command and connection as right now if an exception is thrown/caught your connection will remain open.